# Stored procedure to Update records with Table name

Tags: sql-server

I have a scenario where I have database with multiple tables like TableA, TableB and TableC and also have a table called `Watermarktable`. All tables (TableA, TableB...) have a column `DateLoaded`.

I am storing the values of table names (TableA, TableB...) and DateLoaded (for TableA, TableB...) in a `Watermark` table in same database.

My `Watermark` table to have rows Table name and `DateLoaded`. So each time when my table (TableA , TableB...) gets updated with new `DateLoaded` value, my value in the `Watermark` table should also change for that corresponding table.

I am looking for a simple stored procedure to achieve this. Thanks

Here you go :

Start

```
TableA                        TableB                              TableC

Col1 Col2 LoadDate     Col1 Col2 LoadDate           Col1 Col2 Loaddate
r1    r1   01/01/2019    rs1   rs1  01/02/2019         ra1    ra1   01/01/2019
r2    r2   01/01/2019    rs2    rs2   01/02/2019       ra2    ra2   01/01/2019
```

WaterMark table:

```
Table Name         DateLoaded
-----------------------------------
TableA             01/01/2019
TableB             01/02/2019
TableC             01/01/2019
```

Now Tomorrow if the new data comes in table A and B, my watermark table should be like this:

```
Table Name         DateLoaded
---------------------------------
TableA             12/31/2019
TableB             12/31/2019
TableC             01/01/2019
```

Note here: `DateLoaded` remains same for a table throughout. It does not differ with rows. Thanks again

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Having dynamic tables is your *real* problem here.

Comment: No tables are not dynamic. Have 10 tables that remains constant

Comment: Which you, according to your question, need to dynamically reference. Sample data and expected results would be useful here.

Comment: if you write a collection of after update trigger for all tables your problem is solved. if you dont have force for write sp

Comment: I need a sp for this.since it is going to be repeatable for my other databases. Added a sample values

Comment: And your example data proves exactly my point. *"Having dynamic tables is your real problem here."* There is no such syntax as `SELECT * FROM WaterMark WM JOIN WM.[Table Name] TN ON ...` That isn't how SQL works. An objects name must be a literal it cannot be replaced by the value of a column or variable. You could *only* achieve this with dynamic SQL; but the real solution is fixing your design

Comment: You can easily get when the last time a table had an insert or update done if you have a datetime column which will update itself after every insert/update eliminating the need for an extra dynamic table that you need to maintain. As @Larnu commented, the real solution is fixing your design. As far as your solution is concerned, you can use AFTER UPDATE/AFTER INSERT triggers.

Comment: I didnt get the last point. My tables has a datetime column which updates after every insert so what I need is to update my values for that particular rows. What kind of fix are we talking from design prespective.

Comment: Why not make a `UNION` of `MAX` dates from each table? If I understand your problem (and that is a maybe) WaterMark can be a **VIEW** instead of a **TABLE**

Comment: you wants one sp for all table of your database? if you have this senario the execution point of your sp is dumb and you should execute your sp in a schedule time as job you can create the trigger or one sp forech table dynamicaly with DQE(dynamic query execuation) for all table. my prefer is trigger. if you create one sp foreach table you can call after insert or update command in orm

Comment: if you want to keep history of change your data you can use temporar table or cdc in sql server

Comment: I dont want to keep the history and I dont have to create a View. There is something I am trying to achieve using Azure Data Factory and for that I need a stored procedure and yes I am hoping to have one SP which will update my Watermark table which contains tables name of my database and the last time they were updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code as sp but be carefull about the table and schema name.

i tried to write my code like as your problem

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(50)

CREATE TABLE #LocalDateTBL
(
TableName nvarchar(50),
LoadDate datetime
)

DECLARE TBL_Cursor CURSOR 
FOR
SELECT '['+S.NAME+'].'+'['+T.NAME+']'
FROM SYS.TABLES T
INNER JOIN SYS.SCHEMAS S ON T.SCHEMA_ID = S.SCHEMA_ID
WHERE TYPE='U'


OPEN TBL_Cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM TBL_Cursor
INTO @TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN


    DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @Command = 'INSERT INTO #LocalDateTBL SELECT '+CHAR(39)+ @TableName +CHAR(39)+', MAX(LoadDate) FROM '+@TableName

    PRINT(@Command)

    --EXEC(@Command)

FETCH NEXT FROM TBL_Cursor
INTO @TableName
END
CLOSE TBL_Cursor
DEALLOCATE TBL_Cursor



UPDATE C
SET C.LoadDate = T.LoadDate
FROM WaterMark C
INNER JOIN #LocalDateTBL T ON C.TableName = T.TableName



DROP TABLE #LocalDateTBL
```

this code generate a query for get max LoadDate from foreach table of your database the insert the date into the temp table and update watermark table from temp table.

its better to use the object_id of each table in watermark table instead of table name.

and if you wants you can add new bussiness for add new table in watermark table in this solution